# drop columns with multiple elements pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file1 with

```
col0 col1 
g1   text
g2   text,text
g3   text,text,text
g4   text
g5   text,text,text,text,text
```

need to modify it using pandas to remove all rows with multiple text output should look like this

```
col0 col1 
g1   text
g4   text
```

only difference i have files which have ~300,000 rows in total

Comment: are those strings or lists of strings?

Comment: list of string i guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `col1` contains flat strings:

```
In [94]: df
Out[94]:
  col0                      col1
0   g1                      text
1   g2                 text,text
2   g3            text,text,text
3   g4                      text
4   g5  text,text,text,text,text

In [95]: df = df.loc[~df.col1.str.contains(',')]

In [96]: df
Out[96]:
  col0  col1
0   g1  text
3   g4  text
```

---

```
In [105]: df
Out[105]:
  col0                            col1
0   g1                          [text]
1   g2                    [text, text]
2   g3              [text, text, text]
3   g4                          [text]
4   g5  [text, text, text, text, text]

In [106]: df.col1.str.len() < 2
Out[106]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool

In [107]: df[df.col1.str.len() < 2]
Out[107]:
  col0    col1
0   g1  [text]
3   g4  [text]
```

Comment: can you please explain the first block of code `df = df.loc[~df.col1.str.contains(',')]`

Comment: @novicebioinforesearcher if your column contains flat strings then we know that the `text` values must be separated by commas.  If there exist even one comma then there must be more than one `text` value.  MaxU then filters the dataframe for things that do not have any commas because only those rows are ones with only one `text` value.

Answer (score 2):

This answer was based on @MaxU's concept, but this adds a layer of generalization enabling you to change the condition of how many `text` values are allowed.

```
df[df.col1.str.count(',') < 1]

  col0  col1
0   g1  text
3   g4  text

​
```